# There are non trivial homomorphism from $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z$ into $\Bbb Z$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

I think...
For an irrational number $r$, the map $f(r+\Bbb Z)=1$, and $f(a+\Bbb Z)=0$, for a not in the subgroup generated by $r+\Bbb Z$ generates ahomomorphism from $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z$ into $\Bbb Z$.
Am I Right?

Comment: No, the map $f$ that you have defined is not a homomorphism - its kernel is not a subgroup of ${\mathbb R}/{\mathbb Z}$. Note that ${\mathbb R}/{\mathbb Z}$ is a divisible group but ${\mathbb Z}$ is not.

Comment: What if $a=\frac12r?$

Comment: You are right..thank you

Comment: You may have more luck “finding“ a nontrivial homomorphism $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z\to \Bbb Q$.

Comment: Why the close votes? The OP has made an attempt to solve the problem. The attempt was unsuccessful of course! I see that the close votes are for lack of clarity, but surely the question being asked is clear, and the answer is no.

Comment: @DerekHolt I am not sure, but perhaps it was influenced by the  [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4621724/the-factor-group-r-z-has-subgroups-isomorphic-to-z-q-z-has-not) of the OP.

Answer (score 5):

There is no such nontrivial homomorphism. Otherwise we would get a nontrivial homomorphism $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{Z}$ (by composing with the quotient map $\pi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$).

And such map cannot exist because if $f(x)=a\neq 0$ then what would $f\big(x/(2\cdot a)\big)$ be? You can apply the same argument to your map to see where it fails.